# Bootstrap.min.css calendar not working with full calendar Pop Up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have this modal pop up in the full calendar after drag and drop event over the calendar i'm trying to access the bootstrap eonasdan *datetimepicker* as it works before the modal pop up when used, but after modal pop up it does not show modal pop up. As i have used these CDN for reference on the page for bootstrap datetimepicker.

```
<%--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">--%>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

as i comment the top bootstrap.min.css the modal pop up works but the calendar does not as the bootstrap calendar is in the modal pop up as well.
Here are the snap shot for it.

Here is the bootstrap calendar before modal pop up for temporary use
[image: Before]

Here is the event after drag and drop

[image: event drag and drop]

Here is the bootstrap calendar with in Modal Pop Up after clicking the event

[image: Modal pop up calendar]

As the commenting the css cdn it works but after removing the comment the modal pop up stops working when click on the event.
If it is commented then bootstrap calendar works but as the last image it does not show the design.

```
%--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">--%>
```

Comment: you probably need to change the z-index of the datepicker

Comment: The thing is after commenting the above css link modal pop up works but the datetimepicker of third image shows without design. If i remove comment the modal pop up stops working but the datetimepicker calendar works of the first image. I'm using two bootstrap.min.css one version is of 4.3.1 which is local and another is of 3.3.6 using CDN but without 3.3.6 the eonasdan datetimepicker design won't show and without 4.3.1 the modal pop up won't work also.

Comment: "I'm using two bootstrap.min.css"...you can't do that, they will conflict with each other. Choose a version and stick to it. If one of your components requires a specific version of bootstrap, you either have to base the rest of your site on that same bootstap version, or you have to replace your component with something different.

Comment: Found a solution used $('#ModalPopUpId').removeAttr("class");
            $('#ModalPopUpId').attr("class", "modal fade in"); actually "modal fade show" is for 4.6.1 and "modal fade in" is for 3.3.6 so it was using 4.6.1 then removed the class and added again